# Query a specfic MongoDB array from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, mongodb, geolocation

This is my MongoDb array, sitting in my database

```
["lnglat"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      float(23.584827)
      [1]=>
      float(46.771111)
    }
```

["lnglat"] means longitude, latitude and has two float numbers, that i'm trying to use as parametters to a GOOGLE MAP javascript function to show a location. 
So, my problem is...

I have some php script that makes a query from Mongo and puts the two float numbers into a variable. The problem is I don't know how to query this array, to make it look like this:

$longlat=array(23.584827, 46.771111)

If I make a query with the name of the field, ["lnglat"], it only shows me on screen the word ARRAY.

Thank you!

Comment: How are you printing it to the screen?

Comment: I have a variable that stores all information from the field, like this: $events = $db_helper->getEvents(); and then I put echo '<p>$events["lnglat"]</p>'

Comment: You cannot echo an array in PHP. You can "dump its contents" with var_dump() or print_r() for example, but you'll have to iterate over an array or print out the specific keys...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`echo $array` will print out `ARRAY` and not its contents.  If you want to see the contents, you can use `var_dump` to print them directly or `print_r` to concatenate them.

```
echo '<p>' . print_r($events, true) . '</p>';
```